# Insert character string between period and digit in R

Tags: r, regex, character, gsub

I have a vector of character strings like so:

```r
test <- c("A1.7","A1.8")
```

and I want to used regular expressions to insert `A1c<=` between the period and digit like so:

```r
A1.A1c<=7 A1.A1c<=8
```

I looked through questions and found @zx8754 similar question; I tried to modify the answer posted in their question but had no luck

```r
insert <- 'A1c<='
n <- 4
old <- test
lhs <- paste0('([[:alpha:]][[:digit:]][[:punct:]]{', n-1, '})([[:digit:]]+)$')
rhs <- paste0('\\1', insert, '\\2')
gsub(lhs, rhs, test)
```

Can anyone direct me as to how to correctly execute this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another pattern:

```
gsub("\\.(\\d+)", "\\.A1c<=\\1", test)  

    ## [1] "A1.A1c<=7" "A1.A1c<=8"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KirRTf/1)

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
insert <- 'A1c<='
test <- c("A1.7","A1.8")
sub("(?<=\\.)(?=\\d)", insert, test, perl=TRUE)
## => A1.A1c<=7 A1.A1c<=8
```

See the [online R demo](https://rextester.com/AZOI98984)

**Details**

- `(?<=\\.)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a dot
- `(?=\\d)` -  a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a digit.

The `sub` function will replace the first occurrence only, and `perl=TRUE` makes it possible to use the lookaround constructs in the pattern (as it is now parsed with the PCRE regex engine).

Comment: What if I want a period and a space after each letter? I can't figure that out...

Comment: Ah. Fixed it: when initials: A BH GK A, then `gsub("([A-Z])", "\\1.", df$initials)` would make A. B.H. G.K. A.